# Java code to use variable value depending on build flag

Tags: java, makefile

makefile that compiles all java files.

Comment: This is, generally speaking, not really possible in Java as you'd do it in C with the `-D` compiler flag. If you need your Java program to behave differently depending on environment, put the values into a configuration file and read it when your program starts up.

Comment: Also, `make` isn't really the build system to use with Java.

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done this multiple times in past is to generate a Java file depending on the flag. If you are using `ant` then this code generation is very simple. Otherwise, you can use a template file with placeholder and do some shell-scripting or similar to generate the file.

Answer (score 1):

In `ant` you can use the [replace task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) to modify files as part of your build.

We do this in our builds, but we use it to modify a Java `.properties` file which the application will read for its configurable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I've written rather pleasant flag-controlled systems using a combination of Google Guice and [Apache CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) to inject flag-controlled variables into constructors.